# How to prepare JSON in Azure Policy

Tags: json, azure, azure-api-management, azureportal

In Azure Policy, How to prepare and return the result as following JSON object.

```
return {   Id : 1, prototype: 'skeleton1', status: 'success'}
```

The value will be dynamically set to JSON data in policy.

When use straight as above JSON string then, its fail and unable to save the policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a dynamic data response, then you probably need to look at the set-body policy and liquid templates:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2017/09/25/deep-dive-on-set-body-policy/

For static response data, you can also use the set-body policy like this:

```
<set-body>{
   "Id" : 1, 
   "prototype": "skeleton1", 
   "status": "success"
}</set-body>
```

This will result in the required body.

Comment: How to set values in JSON. Like, replace <id> value by 1, <proptotype> is "skeleton1". Tried with Liquid template, says, not valid attribute. Any alternate is alsofine without liquid.

Comment: Can you add what the response object from the backend looks like? In the link to the deep dive post, the response is dynamically created by placeholders like '{{body.order.id}}'. I'm not sure about the 'not valid attribute' message you get.